# How do I position and size JLabels in Java?

Tags: java, jframe, jlabel

I want to be able to position my two JLabels but when I change the values in the position lines it does nothing. Also when I run it only the second label is displayed.

My code:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

public class cubeTimerClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        window(); //Runs the window method
    }

    public static void window() {
        //Create a window
                JFrame window = new JFrame(); //Create the window object
                window.setSize(900, 600); //Set the size of the window
                window.setTitle("Cube Timer"); //Set the title of the window
                window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); //Tells the program to quit when user closes the window
                window.setVisible(true); //Make the window visible

                //Create a label
                JLabel label1 = new JLabel(""); //Create the label1 object
                label1.setText("Message 1"); //Set the text for label1
                label1.setAlignmentX(0);
                label1.setAlignmentY(0);
                window.add(label1); //Place the label on the window

                //Create a label
                JLabel label2 = new JLabel(""); //Create the label2 object
                label2.setText("Message 2"); //Set the text for label2
                label2.setAlignmentX(0);
                label2.setAlignmentY(50);
                window.add(label2); //Place the label on the window
    }
}
```

Comment: You should start by reading that [Visual Guide to Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html). And of course the `JLabel.setAlignment()` documentation as this is not what it is for.

Comment: If you want to set the position of your labels yourself you need to remove the layout manager (setting `null`). However, that's not recommended and you should first read into the topic that AxelH linked (the entire topic, not just the linked part).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check with this -

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JPanel panel = (JPanel) frame.getContentPane();
    panel.setLayout(null);

    JLabel label = new JLabel("Java");
    panel.add(label);
    Dimension size = label.getPreferredSize();
    label.setBounds(90, 100, size.width, size.height);

    frame.setSize(300, 200);
    frame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: That worked for me, I don't understand the line "Dimension size = label.getPreferredSize();". Am I correct in saying it calculates the size the label needs to be for the text in it then sets the variables 'width' and 'height' accordingly?

Comment: Yes, here null layout is used.Need to calculate the size depending on the text added to JLabel.